# why do only some JSON subcategories use "[" and some other "{"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In JSON, subcategories are sometimes defined using "{" and at other times using "[".

in this example: games -> box -> template , why "[" after games only?

How should the following XML be defined in JSON. How and when should I use "[" and "{"?

```
<games>
  <game id="21934">
      <name>Star Wars: The Old Republic</name>
      <popularity>30</popularity>
   </game>
</games>
```

**Can you give me a good comparison with XML ?**

```
"games": [
    {
        "name": "Star Wars: The Old Republic",
        "popularity": 30,
        "id": 21934,
        "giantbomb_id": 24205,
        "box": {
            "template": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Star%20Wars%3A%20The%20Old%20Republic-{width}x{height}.jpg",
            "small": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Star%20Wars%3A%20The%20Old%20Republic-52x72.jpg",
            "medium": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Star%20Wars%3A%20The%20Old%20Republic-136x190.jpg",
            "large": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Star%20Wars%3A%20The%20Old%20Republic-272x380.jpg"
        },
```

Comment: Array vs Object. Two different data structures.

Comment: There is [documentation for JSON](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can best answer this question by reading the [documentation at json.org](http://json.org/).

[ ] are used to define arrays, whereas { } are used to declare objects. Objects are really a form of associative array (mapping name indices to values instead of number
 indices  to values). In JSON arrays however, the number indices are implicit.

The main advantages of JSON are that it is a subset of Javascript and that it is a compact data interchange format when compared to XML, which is more verbose. JSON data only needs minimal validation whereas XML requires complex parsing. JSON also sacrifices the so called readabilty element of XML, although personally speaking I find it easier to scan JSON to find mistakes than I do wading through XML elements and attributes.

To take your games example, in XML a list of games would be something like this:

```xml
<games>
    <game id="21934">
        <name>Star Wars: The Old Republic</name>
        <type>MMORG</type>
    </game>
    <!-- more game blocks here -->
    <game id="12345">...</game>
</games>
```

In the above example I have skipped niceties such as declaring the fact it is an XML document, linking the above file to a Data Type Definition (DTD) etc.

In JSON the file would probably just be something like this:

```js
{
    "games": [
    { "id": 21934, "name" : "Star Wars: The Old Republic", "type": "MMORG" },
    { "id": 12345, .... }
    ]
}
```

You could read the above object directly into a Javascript variable and it would be accepted as valid javascript without further processing. It's much faster and easier to get along with. One thing to note is that despite the fact that "games" is an array of objects, it has been encapsulated in {} to be read as a single object.

So in summary, XML is a formal way of exchanging information, whereas JSON sacrifices the formality for ease and speed of use. Be warned however that JSON does have rules and very minor infractions can cause failure to read some or all of the data, depending on browser implementation.

Comment: No problem - it gave me something to do whilst watching my daughter go to sleep :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` syntax is for arrays where you locate members by number.

The `{}` syntax is for objects where you locate members by name.

Comment: @thenewseattle: Arrays and objects (associative arrays) are common data structures in many languages. That's what you want to learn about, how to use them and what is the difference. JSON is like a subset of JavaScript (not quite but very similar), so I'd start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array